# Not able to turn off password autocomplete using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am not able to make autocomplete turn off for password field in IE11 using jQuery and this is the code I am using (I have tried various options but still not make autocomplete turn off for password field in IE11..including the above one)

```
 <form action='a2.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' name='username'>
 <input type='password' name='password'class='password'>
 <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('password').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
  });
  </script>
```

The above code works fine in Chrome but not in IE11

Comment: Why don't you do : `<input type='password' name='password'class='password' autocomplete="off">`

Comment: It's not a duplicate I tried with my code now I am not able to make it work..I didn't get the answer I want..The autocomplete=off will not work in IE11

Comment: The question which has been refered to is removed now. [Turning off AutoComplete feature for Passwords in IE11 using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988275/turning-off-autocomplete-feature-for-passwords-in-ie11-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

As of Internet Explorer 11, the autocomplete property is no longer supported for input type=password fields.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is not valid. Try one of the following:

```
$('input[type="password"]')

$('[name="password"]')

$('.password')
```

You could just add the attribute to the markup directly without using JavaScript though. Not sure why you'd want to add the attribute this way.

**Update:**

Added the class selector as suggested by [sdespont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996968/not-able-to-turn-off-password-autocomplete-using-jquery/21997018#comment-33338257) in the comment section below.

Also, please be sure to read [E.J. Brennan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996968/not-able-to-turn-off-password-autocomplete-using-jquery/21997018#answer-21997083) answer. It explains why the `autocomplete` attribute is not working in IE 11.

Comment: I have tried all and it's not working :( So there is no other go?

Comment: There were multiple problems with your original code. First was an incorrect selector, which I showed a fix for in my answer above. The second is the loss of support in IE 11 for this property on password fields which @ELBrennan discusses in his answer. Unfortunately, I don't know of a fix for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.password').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
  });
  </script>
```